# Swift popToRoot not working

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, root

[image: www.dropbox.com/s/jrzrst5qtfq6op2/Screenshot%202015-03-20%2022.27.42.png?dl=0]

This highlighted line is where should popToRoot proceed, after a successful registration it should redirect to Root View Controller. For some reason it's not working for me, literally nothing happens, not even error.

I tried with

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: Have you checked if the `navigationController` property is not nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to be using navigation controller at all, so I'd wager that `self.navigationController` is `nil`.

You could use an unwind segue. So in your root view controller, add a method like so:

```
@IBAction func unwindToRoot(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("successfully unwound")
}
```

Then in your scoreboard scene from which you want to unwind, you can <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the button to the "exit outlet":

[image]

When you let go, you can pick the unwind action:

[image]

This achieves the "pop to root" sort of functionality, but is not contingent upon using navigation controller.

---

If you want to perform this unwind programmatically, rather than doing the segue from the button to the exit outlet, do it from the view controller icon to the exit outlet:

[image]

Then, select the segue  in the document outline and give this segue a unique storyboard id:

[image]

Then you can programmatically perform the segue, using the same identifier string:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("UnwindToRoot", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried but it crashes for some reason. But let's get to that later. Is this way working with my if statement. It's basically register form with some error checkings(If fields are empty, and Parse back-end errors ). 

If error != nil { //Error } else { //Unwind segue? } 

Can it work like this ?

Comment: You can create a "manual segue" by control-dragging from the view controller icon to the exit icon; then give that segue a unique identifier and then you can perform it programmatically with `performSegueWithIdentifier`. See expanded answer.